# Реализация задания каскадного удаления в миграциях для полиморфных отношений

Tags: php, laravel

Наше Вам с кисточкой, уважаемые!

Вот реализация каскадного удаления связанных данных из зависимой таблицы:

```
class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('categories', static function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('category_id', 'categories_ibfk_1')
                ->references('id')->on('categories')
                ->onUpdate('CASCADE')
                ->onDelete('CASCADE');
        });
    }
...
}
```

Как реализовать подобное в миграции с полиморфным отношением?

```
class CreateImagesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('images', static function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->morphs('imageable');
            $table->string('path');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полиморфное отношение не создает связь в базе данных, поэтому ссылочную целостность обеспечивать нужно только кодом

Comment: @Ivan_Dudarev: это точно, Иван?

Comment: @Yakoffka точнее некуда. Посмотрите [исходный код метода `morphs()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v7.16.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L1308). Он просто добавляет строковое поле, целочисленное поле и простой индекс. Для обеспечения ссылочной целостности необходимо добавить внешний ключ, но внешнему ключу нужно знать таблицу, в которой находится связанная строка (а заранее эта таблица неизвестна, т.к. зависит от значения какого-то поля в конкретной строке).

Comment: @Ivan_Dudarev: Я понял Вас. Большое спасибо.